# How can I run a statement when modal close on vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
    <b-modal ref="modal" id="modalInvoice" size="lg"  title="Invoice">
        <Invoice/>
        <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100"> 
            <b-btn size="sm" class="float-right" variant="warning" @click="show=false">
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
            </b-btn>
        </div>
    </b-modal>

    ...
        <b-btn variant="warning" class="btn-square mt-2" v-b-modal.modalInvoice @click="checkout()"><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt"></i>Checkout</b-btn>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        mounted() {
            $(this.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
                console.log('close modal')
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

I try like that. So I try using `ref="modal"` and mounted. But it does not works. If modal close, the console.log is not show

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of  `@click="show=false"` add a function that changes `show` property and does what you need?

Comment: Could you provide us some more information? 1. B-modal is your component or is it from some framework or library? 2. Are you sure that the event is emitted properly so the error is only in catching the event? 3. Are you sure that it is the b-modal component that emits the event (not the button or the invoice)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an event listener on the modal component:

```
<b-modal ref="modal" id="modalInvoice" size="lg"  title="Invoice" @hidden="onHidden">
    <Invoice/>
    <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100"> 
        <b-btn size="sm" class="float-right" variant="warning" @click="show=false">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print
        </b-btn>
    </div>
</b-modal>

methods: {
  onHidden (e) {
    console.log('the modal was hidden')
  }
}
```

All the events are listed under the [Component Reference](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal) section.

Comment: Maybe you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363283/how-to-display-content-by-page-number-or-prev-next-clicked-on-the-vue