# Vue b-modal @close look like it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

The following is my b-modal code:

```html
<b-modal
  centered
  id="modal-center"
  title="product regist"
  body-class="p-0 m-0"
  size="col-md-6 col-sm-6"
  ok-title="regist"
  cancel-title="cancel"
  @ok="registerProduct"
  @cancel="cancelRegister"
  @close="cancelRegister"
>
  ...
</b-modal>
```

`cancelRegister` method will initialize (e.g date or category)

When I click on `cancel` button in the modal, the method is fired and works normally. But when I close the modal (e.g click another part click), it doesn't work.

I found some informations at `bootstrap-vue` docs, but I can't find anything related to this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a statement when modal close on vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270865/how-can-i-run-a-statement-when-modal-close-on-vue)

Comment: `close` not triggering on backdrop click is not an error. The documentation on `close` is pretty clear: "When default header close button pressed, just before modal has hidden.". It only triggers on the header's X button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#comp-ref-b-modal-events), we may consider to add a new function to handle all hide events.

First remove the `@cancel="cancelRegister"` and `@close="cancelRegister"` and replace it with `@hide=hideRegister`.

Add the following in method:

```
hideRegister(bvModalEvent) {
  const cancelEvents = ['cancel', 'esc', 'backdrop', 'headerclose']
  if(cancelEvents.includes(bvModalEvent.trigger)) {
   this.cancelRegister()
  }
}
```

Please refer to [the documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#prevent-closing) for the possible `BvModalEvent.trigger` values.